# transform origin 50% vertical

Tags: css, animation, transform

I am making some cards that flip on hover but can't get the transform origin to work vertically. They should have a 50% origin so that they go as much upwards as downwards but they always just push downwards.

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/oxVOeL

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="card-container card-1">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
                <h3>Front</h3>
                <p>Front</p>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <h3>Back</h3>
                <p>Back</p>
                <p><a class="button">Resell with intY</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container card-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
                <h3>Front</h3>
                <p>Front</p>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <h3>Back</h3>
                <p>Back</p>
                <p><a class="button">Resell with intY</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container card-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
                <h3>Front</h3>
                <p>Front</p>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <h3>Back</h3>
                <p>Back</p>
                <p><a class="button">Resell with intY</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

body {padding: 30px;}
.card-container {perspective: 1000; display: inline-block; margin: 0 3rem;}
.card-container:hover .card,
.card-container.hover .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
}
.card-container, .front, .back {
    width: 210px;
    height: 297px;
}
.card {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
     transform-origin: 50%;
}
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
.front {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #122d40;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);   /* for firefox 31 */
}
.back {
    background-color: #1f7c8f;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two considerations here, the horizontal position and the vertical position.

To maintain the horizontal positon, you need to compute the correct value for the `transform-origin`.

You added padding to the `.front` and `.back` elements, which increases the width of the element by 40px total.

You can use the CSS `calc` function to compute the offset as `calc(50% - 20px)`, and that seems to work.

To fix the issue with the vertical placement of the flipped `.card`, on hover, you scale up the size of `.card` by 1.1, so to keep the flipped vertically centered with respect to the other elements, you could add the `top` offset to the transition.

For example, if your card is 160px in height, the card will be 16px taller, so offset set `top: -8x` (since `.card` is relatively positioned).

```css
body {padding: 30px;}
.card-container {perspective: 1000; display: inline-block; margin: 0 2rem;}
.card-container:hover .card,
.card-container.hover .card {
 transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
    top: -8px; /* compute offset: 160*0.1/2 = 8 */
}
.card-container, .front, .back {
 width: 100px;
 height: 160px;
}
.card {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 position: relative;
    top: 0;
 transform-origin: calc(50% + 20px);
}
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}
.front {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: #122d40;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg); /* for firefox 31 */
}
.back {
 background-color: #1f7c8f;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="card-container card-1">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h3>Front</h3>
        <p>Front</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h3>Back</h3>
        <p>Back</p>
        <p><a class="button">Resell with intY</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container card-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h3>Front</h3>
        <p>Front</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h3>Back</h3>
        <p>Back</p>
        <p><a class="button">Resell with intY</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container card-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h3>Front</h3>
        <p>Front</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h3>Back</h3>
        <p>Back</p>
        <p><a class="button">Resell with intY</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's it. I took the 20px padding off and it made no difference the card still pushes downwards when you hover.

Comment: @TheReveller Sorry, I misunderstood the problem.  Can you clarify? When you hover on the card, where is the top edge of the card suppose to be?  So, when you hover, the card is 1.1 times larger, so to top edge of the flipped card should be slightly higher than the non-flipped cards and likewise, the bottom edge slightly below by the same amount?

Comment: @TheReveller I made another attempt at a solution, please take a look when you have a moment, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Marc. That did it. I am at a loss to understand why I can't set the vertical origin though. Adding a position feels like a hack.